# Selecting date from datepicker

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium, can anyone suggest how to click required date from the date picker. Here is the scenarios in attached screen shot[image]

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this piece of code and let me know if there is any issue

```
List<WebElement> alldates = driver.findElements(by.id('locator of the date picker which conatins all dates in it'));
    for (WebElement dates : alldates) {
                    if (dates.isDisplayed() && dates.isEnabled()
                            && dates.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Date To be Clicked")) {
                        dates.click();
                    }
                }
```